# CVE-2016-8735: Apache Tomcat Remote Code Execution

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

We have a production environment which is running on Apache Tomcat 8.0.32. Apache recently announced a fix for vulnerability 
[Remote Code Execution CVE-2016-8735](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html)  and suggested to migrate the affected Apache Tomcat (versions 8.0.0.RC1 to 8.0.38) to Apache Tomcat 8.0.39.
If we don't want to go ahead with updating to a later version, is there any hot-fix or patch available  that could be applied on top of Apache Tomcat 8.032?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to upgrade the whole package, you'll have to go find the various `svn` commits that fixed the CVE, merge them into your 8.0.38 source package, and then build Tomcat yourself.

Tomcat doesn't publish separate patch sets for CVEs; they instead release an updated version of the whole package.